# Is it possible to install the latest HttpPlatformHandler on an Azure App Service?

Tags: azure

I want to install this:

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler

On one of these:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-value-prop-what-is/
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/app-service/

Is this doable?

Answer (score 0):

[Look at this.](https://azure.microsoft.com/pl-pl/blog/announcing-the-release-of-the-httpplatformhandler-module-for-iis-8/) HttpPlatformHandler is is installed by default in App Service. [Here is a configuration example.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-custom-upload/)